# Pricing of autocallable structured product

Tags: black-scholes, pricing, hedge

I'm looking at this paper: https://doi.org/10.1057/jdhf.2011.25, which is on pricing autocallable structured product. The author uses the Black-Scholes equation to describe the product's dynamic value, that is
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2}+(r-q)S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}-(r+CDS)V=0,
$$
where $CDS$ is the credit default swap spread of the issuer and $V$ is the product value. My question is why it is valid to use BS model to price this kind of structured product?

And, if possible, could anyone tell me what should I do if I want to find out what the Delta and Vega profile of this product looks like? Furthermore, how am I supposed to hedge this product?

I am quite new to quant finance and if there is any mistake in my description, please point it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Do not use BS for AC

Long answer: There are plenty of question here about this already. Typically it is priced via [Monte Carlo](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/47264/54838) but that is not a model, just an implementation of some model (LV, SV, SLV).

Standard would be to use SLV but even there are issues with [decorrelation and bilocality](https://www.risk.net/our-take/6348336/calling-out-autocallable-pricing) if you look at basket AC (which are very common).

There is also an interesting (fun) [tweet](https://twitter.com/nihilisttrader/status/1337549664489443335?lang=en) about AC hedging.

Edit: for Greeks, without a sophisticated tool from a bank or vendor, you will not find anything better than [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37200/barrier-option-autocallable-vega-profile/37231#37231) in my opinion.

With a proper tool, it will be [bump and reprice](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63663/54838). The tweet I included above explains some of the problems you will face with regards to Greeks (or hedging).